# JavaFX - How to create many windows from your main method?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to be able create multiple charts each in different windows, but I am struggling to do so in JavaFX. Because the UI is an 'extra' of the application, I wanted to launch the UI separately and separate it from the main program logic, thus I have the following code:

```
public class UI extends Application {
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage; // I don't really plan on even using this, but I've left this here so that I can break on it.
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return this.stage;
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do other stuff

        Application.launch(UI.class, args);
        UI ui = new UI();
        // I want to create multiple windows (of charts) here, like this:
        Chart c1 = new Chart("c1");
        Chart c2 = new Chart("c2");
    }
}

public class Chart {
    public Chart(String title) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        // ...
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a mess, just like my understanding of JavaFX. In fact, the code executes infinitely because of a loop in the Application class.

I'm very confused as to how I can create multiple stages. From what I've understood, by calling the `Application.launch` method, the Application class then calls the `start` method in the UI class. This does indeed happen, but as mentioned before, it becomes stuck there. However, I don't actually want to create a stage of type UI, I want to create many Chart stages, but it seems that in order for the application to even begin, I must have a `start` method.

Can anyone help me get my desired outcome of creating multiple windows?

Comment: Just as a clarification: it's not the `start(...)` method that is failing to exit, it's the `launch(...)` method. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-): *"The launch method does not return until the application has exited, either via a call to Platform.exit or all of the application windows have been closed."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you're not too far off for creating other windows (stages in JavaFX speak):

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
// ...
stage.show();
```

This is pretty bang on, you can create a stage, then do whatever (usually involving adding a combination of layout boxes / components to a scene, then setting that scene to the stage), then show it. I wouldn't recommend just blindly showing the stage in the constructor, but that's a bit besides the point.

Despite still carry the JavaFX 2 label, [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) is still a good one for getting the basics in this regard.

Two other things look like they're specific points of confusion at present:

- The stage you get access to in the `start()` method is, essentially, just a stage created and given to you for convenience. Treat it like any other, though of course you don't need to create it first! (Heck, in many cases you can even ignore it and just create your own stages if that helps you understand things better.)
- The classic `main()` method shouldn't actually be called *at all* in a properly loaded JFX application, so don't do anything in it other than `Application.launch()`. That's just a fail safe. The real entry point for a JFX application is the start method, so make sure all your logic goes in there (if it seems like nothing in the main method is getting executed, this is why!)

Comment: Sadly I've already been through that tutorial, but it hasn't helped. Their situation is that their main method of their entire program is focused around this JavaFX window. In my case, I want to optionally launch the UI separately. If I try and create a Chart object without first calling the main method in the UI class, I get an: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, message. If I do call the main method of the UI class I get stuck in an infinite loop. Somewhere I must initialize the JavaFX application.

Comment: In fact, I've tried making Program extend Application and put the start method in there like in the examples, as well as putting the launch(args) method in the main method of it. I left the start method empty though since I don't need that stage, but like with the UI class, it just executes infinitely.

Comment: @alwaysboots Can't you just call `stage.show()` in a separate method of your choice rather than right away?

Comment: I could, but the problem is that the application doesn't execute past the `Application.launch(UI.class, args);` line, even if I move the start method and the call to launch to the Program class. It is simply stuck there. It seems like JavaFX wants me to use the `start` method as the barer of the program logic.

Comment: @alwaysboots As I said, you shouldn't use the `main()` method in a JavaFX application for anything other than calling `Application.launch`, since you have no guarantees it will ever be executed (hopefully it won't if the app is launched properly!) Likewise you should never put that line anywhere other than the main method, otherwise of course you will enter an infinite loop. So yes, you should (must) use the start() method and the start() method only to begin your application logic.

Comment: I see! So is there any way for me to launch my UI outside of the main program logic, or must I make the Program class extend Application? I have tried doing this and it works, but it's not really what I wanted to achieve. I didn't want to have Program extend Application and have the `start` method there from which I will call the rest of my program logic.

Comment: The class that has your `start()` method in must extend `Application`, yes - but from that method, you can call whatever other class you like to create the rest of your logic (and that class of course won't have to extend `Application`.) The `start()` method has to be the *entry point* for the application - but you certainly don't have to (and shouldn't) put all the code for your application logic in that method alone!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I get it now. I don't like the design choice they've made since you can't separate the UI from the main application logic since the Application class' main method takes that position, but that's Oracle's fault...

Comment: @alwaysboots If you want to separate the UI from the main application logic, move all the UI code out of `Application.start(...)` and use `Application.start(...)` to do solely what its name implies it should do: start the application.

Comment: @James_D That is indeed what I'm doing, but my point is that you can't escape running the `start` method in your application. Either you run it when you load up your program, or you have to make a call to the `launch` method somewhere else and then return back to your code from the `start` method (which is messy). If your application wouldn't necessarily load anything JavaFX related, you'd have the overhead of the `Application` class on your program whether you like it or not.

Comment: @alwaysboots I don't see why it's that much different to the fact that you have to have a `main(...)` method in a regular Java application. You have to start the application somewhere. If your application might use JavaFX, then you somehow need to ensure the JavaFX toolkit is started, which is taken care of for you by `Application.start(...)`. This mechanism also makes it much harder to execute JavaFX code on the wrong thread, and I suspect it's (at least partly) a reaction to so much incorrect swing code that's around.